# Saving iPhone Address Book Contacts via Text Document

Tags: iphone, ios

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to save the address book of an iPhone via Text Document. I've been searching but haven't found anything useful.

I want to be able to plug in my phone, save the contacts on a text document and that's it.

Comment: You will have to write something that iterates over all the contacts and all their properties. There is no system provided function to do this.

Answer (score 0):

That is pretty easy. Just take a close look at the [Address Book Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007744), especially the section "Direct Interaction: Programmatically Accessing the Database". You will see that it is trivial to get all the records.

```
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
CFMutableArrayRef peopleMutable = CFArrayCreateMutableCopy(
                                          kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                          CFArrayGetCount(people),
                                          people
                                  );
```

Now all you have to do is to iterate through `peopleMutual`and extract the data with the functions like

```
NSString* name = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABRecordCopyValue(person,
                                           kABPersonFirstNameProperty);
```

for the various properties.

Write all these out to a text file and upload, send with email or present in a web view or text view for copy pasting.